# Repeating the same statement using loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

This is the same statement for 3 times. how to do this with loop. Here, the matrix G1  dimension is 3*10. so in each part i am taking different column.

```
G2 = f_range_m(1:8:length(timeline_ms),:); %%%% measured range
G1 = OrgiRange(1:8:end,:);

M1 = G1(:,1);
dist11 = abs(bsxfun( @minus,G2,M1));
[~,col1] = min(dist11,[],2);
Result_1 = diag(G2(:,col1));


M2 = G1(:, 2);
dist22 = abs(bsxfun(@minus,G2, M2));
[~,col2] = min(dist22,[],2);
Result_2 = diag(G2(:,col2));

M3 = G1(:, 3);
dist33 = abs(bsxfun(@minus,G2, M3));
[~,col3] = min(dist33,[],2);
Result_3 = diag(G2(:,col3));
```

I am trying this way. However not getting desired output. Result dimension should be 13*3.

```
obj = 3;
for ix = 1:obj
    M = G1(:,ix);
    dist = abs(bsxfun(@minus,G2,M));
    [~,col] = min (dist,[],2);
    Result = diag(G2(:,col));
end
```

Comment: Sorry, G1 is 13*3 and G2 is 13*50

Comment: The problem with your code are the variable names you are using. You have to use arrays or cell arrays instead of variable names like `M1` `M2` `M3`. If you rewrite the code this way, going to a loop is straight forward. You just replace the `M{1}` with a `M{ix}` where ix is your loop iterator. Alternatively if you don't need M after the calculation just use `M` and overwrite it in each iteration. Do the same for `dist`, `col` and `Result` and you got a solution.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your updated code you nearly solved it. Everything which remains is writing to the columns of `Result` instead of overwriting it in each iteration.

```
obj = 3;
Result=nan(size(G1,1),obj);
for ix = 1:obj
    M = G1(:,ix);
    dist = abs(bsxfun(@minus,G2,M));
    [~,col] = min (dist,[],2);
    Result(:,ix) = diag(G2(:,col));
end
```